# Javascript Button in Chrome Packaged App

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-app

I'm working on a chrome app but can't seem to get html/JS buttons working. In my background.js file, I have the following code:

```
chrome.app.window.create('window.html', {
        // TODO- pick a more appropriate window size, create UI
        'bounds': {
            'width': 400,
            'height': 500
        }
    }, function(appWin){
        pageDocument = appWin.contentWindow.document;
        pageDocument.getElementById("Listen").onclick = function(){
            // do stuff
        });
});
```

I had at first tried just using "document" without getting the pageDocument object from the content window and that didn't work, as "document" was undefined. However, this new code won't even let me open the application, so I'm having trouble figuring out what's wrong. It's definitely something in the getElementById.onclick function, as the app opens with no error messages if I comment that specific part out- but I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Why are you not doing this from within `window.html`? It would be far more appropriate there than in `background.js`.

Comment: The button itself is in window.html. However, I need to call a Javascript function when it's pressed and Chrome apps don't support inline Javascript.

Comment: Yes, they don't support _inline_ JavaScript. But `<script src="window.js">` is fine.

Comment: Doesn't seem like it...? When I try to use script src in window.html I get the same inline JS error: 
`Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.`

Comment: Oh, right. Sorry. You can't _assign_ `onclick` _attribute_. You need to attach a listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to assign `onclick` on any element is forbidden by Chrome CSP, as this counts as inline code.

You should be attaching an event listener, and it would make much more sense in `window.html` itself.

```
// window.js, include in window.html

// Required to ensure #Listen exists
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  // Attach event listeners, not inline onclick attribute
  document.getElementById("Listen").addEventListener("click", function() {
    /* your event processing */
  });
});
```